# Dev express ASPXGridview close row after insert. e.cancel has gone?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, devexpress

How do you close a row on an ASPXGridView after running the RowUpdated event serverside. In the 9.3 version, you just needed to call to close the row after an insert, but

```
grid.CancelEdit()
e.cancel = true
```

I now have v11 and the e.cancel option has been removed from DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataUpdatedEventArgs, however, its still showing on the v11 API

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_RowUpdatingtopic

Comment: Check the link to the help topic: it refers to the ASPxGridView.RowUpdating event (not the ASPxGridView.RowUpdated event - http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_RowUpdatedtopic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are talking about two different events:

- ASPxGridView.RowUpdating
- ASPxGridView.RowUpdated

The ASPxGridView.RowUpdating event offer the eventArgs' e.Cancel property for canceling this event.

The ASPxGridView.RowUpdated event does not offer it, because the DataRow is already updated and the changes are posted to the underlying data source.

Comment: Thank you for your help, It was a stressful day and I have completely used the wrong event!